emacsclient says "No connection could be made.."
(I'm not sure if this is a windows-only problem, may other OSs just don't crash as often)
I used to start one emacs window and my .emacs has a line (server-start) which starts the server. Then I open files from command line by running emacsclient.exe. After a crash and a reboot this doesn't work anymore. emacsclient writes following error message:
C:\Program Files\Emacs\emacs-28.1\bin\emacsclient.exe: connect: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
C:\Program Files\Emacs\emacs-28.1\bin\emacsclient.exe: No socket or alternate editor.  
Please use:
        --server-file      (or environment variable EMACS_SERVER_FILE)
        --alternate-editor (or environment variable ALTERNATE_EDITOR)


In the *Warnings* buffer I found following warning:
Warning (server): Unable to start the Emacs server.
There is an existing Emacs server, named "server".
To start the server in this Emacs process, stop the existing
server or call 'M-x server-force-delete' to forcibly disconnect it.

The reason was that the crash terminated emacs and left the file ~/.emacs.d/server/server behind. Closing emacs, deleting this file and restarting emacs solved the problem.
Saying M-x server-force-delete and M-x server-start inside emacs would also do the job.
